# How to set/access external swf file's dynamic text field in action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fla

I am working in  a fla file where i added a swf file.

How I set a text on that swf file's dynamic text. Is there any to to direct set text. I don't want to pass as parameter in url.

I tried like this

```
var rq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("subwindow/Time_date.swf");
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
ldr.load(rq);

function done(e:Event):void
{
   var externalSWF:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget.content);

    // I have dynamic text field named dDate. I tried like this but got error
    externalSWF.dDate.text = "tdfdfd";       
    addChild(externalSWF);
}
```

I got error

> Error #1069: Property dDate not found on
>   Time_date_fla.MainTimeline_*Preloader*_ and there is no default value.

Please advice me

Comment: what error? it the path to the textfield correct?

Comment: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property dDate not found on Time_date_fla.MainTimeline__Preloader__ and there is no default value.
----
if i skip this line 
externalSWF.dDate.text = "tdfdfd";  
 then the clip add successfully.

Comment: it seems that dDate is not accessible. Does the textfield exist on all frames? maybe you are using different scenes? Is the textfield in the root? Or is it in another movieclip?
is Time_date_fla.MainTimeline_Preloader_  the movieclip the textfield is in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using `TLF` text in your loaded swf?

in Time_date.fla goto `file> publishSettings> actionScriptSettings> runtimeSharedLibrarySettings` and change `defaultLinkage` to `mergedIntoCode`

you can read more about this problem [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/loading-child-swfs-tlf-content.html)

hope this helps